# Text getting reversed to 360 degrees using Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabricjs to render group of ellipse and text . But when I drag to top left and to more left the text becomes as if you are watching the text on a mirror .

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/6CDFr/266/) .

Code :

```
var gCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvDraw');
gCanvas.setWidth(500);
gCanvas.setHeight(500);

var myEllipse = new fabric.Ellipse({
  top: 250,
  left: 100,
  rx: 75,
  ry: 50,
  fill: '#999999',
  stroke: '#000000',
  strokeWidth: 2
});
//gCanvas.add(myEllipse);

var myText = new fabric.Text("Some text", {
  top: 250,
  left: 250,
});
//gCanvas.add(myText);


// set up a listener for the event where the object has been modified
gCanvas.observe('object:modified', function (e) {
  console.log(e);
  var myObject = e.target;
  if (!myObject._objects) {
    return;
  }
  for (i in myObject._objects) {
    myObject._objects[i].strokeWidth = 2 / Math.sqrt(myObject.scaleX *         myObject.scaleY);
  }
});
var group = new fabric.Group([ myEllipse, myText ], {
  borderColor: 'black',
  cornerColor: 'green'
});
gCanvas.add(group);
```

Comment: I'm dragging my ass off, but I keep seeing the ellipse and "some text" next to it... What should I drag exactly? And to where? Which browser are you using? You are not dragging your monitor around and putting it upside-down, are you?

Comment: Please i cannot see the bug, and also do not post question or fiddle with fabricjs version 0.9 use at least 1.5

Comment: In case you are using the resize handles to flip the object vertically or horizontally, this is expected behavior of fabric. If you want to avoid the flipping, you can set lockScalingFlip: true on your object.

Comment: @forrert yes that worked. Thank you very much. Can you convert your comment to answer , I can accept it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid a fabric object from flipping horizontally or vertically the property `lockScalingFlip` can be set to `true`.